# If a creature is immune to the incapacitated condition but not the unconscious condition, can it still take actions while unconscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, immunities

I suppose the question also applies to petrified, paralyzed, and stunned as they also inflict incapacitated, but unconscious was the strangest to me.

Comment: Related (if not some sort of duplicate): "[Does incapacitated condition immunity give immunity to stun?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79709)". If that question answers yours that'd be great to know, and if it does, know a duplicate wouldn't be a bad thing, in fact it helps with search results and finding similar questions! That all said, welcome to the site! Feel free to take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and visit the [help] if you've got further questions.

Comment: Some other related questions: "[Is a creature immune to the prone condition also immune to being incapacitated by the Tasha's Hideous Laughter spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128267)" and "[Does a condition immunity also apply to its effects from other sources?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105783)".

Comment: This was more of a general case question, but the Warforged Colossus from the new Eberron book is the only creature I can find with Incapacitated immunity, and it lacks Unconscious immunity.

Comment: Yeah it seems that is the only such monster, so if you'd want to use that specific monster feel free to edit it in, otherwise this would have to be a Homebrew monster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A creature immune to the incapacitated condition cannot be incapacitated unless something explicitly ignores this immunity

The [unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Unconscious) condition causes the following effects:

- An unconscious creature is incapacitated, can't move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings.
- The creature drops whatever it's holding and falls prone.
- The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.
- Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.
- Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.

If a creature, such as the Warforged Colossus, were immune to the incapacitated condition then only the first bullet point would be prevented. This means the creature would be unconscious, drop what it's holding, fall prone, be unable to move or speak, be unaware of their surroundings, and so forth. This would prevent the creature from doing a great number of things but it notably would *not* prevent them from taking actions, bonus actions, and reactions, as this is what the incapacitated condition does. Thus, yes, an unconscious Warforged Colossus would be able to take actions as per usual.

However, it is worth pointing out that there are very few ways to apply the unconscious condition to a monster aside from a GM allowing them to make death saves instead of dying outright when reaching zero hit points and a creature choosing to knock a creature unconscious instead of having them die.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "can't move" is kind of ambiguous. A DM would probably be within their prerogative to interpret that as "cannot move their body", rather than "cannot use their Movement". Actions would therefore be limited to those which do not require motion (like an innate fear power, for example). In the case of the Warforged Colossus, perhaps the incinerating beam, but limited to an arc of fire. It would also have to guess *when* to fire, since it is unaware of its surroundings.

Comment: @keithcurtis Yeah the exact extent of "can't move" could probably be it's own question, except I'm not really sure what an answer would draw on...

Comment: I agree. I just wondered if it were worth folding the ambiguity into your answer. I.e. this is a valid interpretation, but not necessarily authoritative. Your call.

Comment: @kiethcurtis No, it’s almost certainly referring to “cannot take movement actions”.

Comment: I disagree, hence the ambiguity. If the intent were that it cannot change its location, the wording would be more like that used in other conditions: "A grappled creature’s speed becomes 0". 

"Can't move", like "speak" or "is unaware" sounds more like plain language rather than game mechanics.

Comment: @nick012000 Here is a question discussing this very thing: '[What's the difference between “can't move” and “speed becomes 0”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159387)"